# /Account/Login hangs when trying to log in to ABP Angular App

Tags: identityserver4, abp

I've got an ABP 3.3.2 app Angular/.net core. It's pretty vanilla. I've done nothing to customise the authentication bits. I'm experiencing an issue where by when I deploy the application to a server and try to login the browser just spins on the POST to /Account/Login before eventually timing out.

I've had this on a Windows VPS and I've just deployed to Azure to see if it was an environment thing but I'm experiencing it there, with the Angular bits deployed to an Azure Storage static site and the API running in an AppService.

I can browse the swagger doc for the API and the, the ABP application configuration /api/abp/application-configuration and the openid-configuration document /.well-known/openid-configuration which I believe proves (indirectly) that the connectionstring is right.

To really spice things up, about 3% of the time, after the request to /Account/Login has spun for a while, if you open the Angular front end in another tab you will actually be logged in. The request to /Account/Login in the other tab will still timeout.

Comment: Can you double check that your redis server is up?

Comment: Yeah, you need to install the redis server, if you haven't done that. I had the same experience. https://redis.io/download

Comment: There's no Redis involved in this.